# unable to get email in facebook login using codeigniter library

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can get firstname, lastname and id in facebook login using codeigniter and js, but couldn't get Email field. I tried many logins. no luck.

Controller:

```
function facebook_login_get(){
    $config = array(
    'appId'  => 'xxx',
    'secret' =>  'xxx',
    'cookie' => true
    );
    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);
    $appid      = 'xxx';
    $appsecret  = 'xxx';
    $facebook   = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appid,
    'secret' => $appsecret,
    'cookie' => true
    ));

    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);        
    $fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($fbuser) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$fbuser.'/?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,id');
            echo "<pre>";print_r($user_profile);exit;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->response ( array (
                "status" => false,
                "error" => $e->getMessage()
            ), 401 );
            exit;   
        }
    }
   }
```

View:

```
<a href='#' class='fb_login'>fb login</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fb_login').click(function(){
            login();
        });
    });
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxx', // App ID
            channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
        });
    };

    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    function login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {
                   window.top.location = 'xxx/accounts/facebook_login';
               });
            }
        }, {scope: 'email'});       

    }
</script>
```

I tried all methods suggested by Google search, but couldn't get the solution for this.

In the FB.login function, I can get an email using autoresponse.email, but couldn't get in the PHP API function.

Please assist me to resolve this.

Comment: Sounds like it might be using a different access token on the server side. The PHP SDK should be able to pick up the access token automatically when cookie is set to true, so try without the getAccessToken/ setAccesstoken lines.

Comment: And getting the user id first is not necessary - you can use `me` in your API request instead of a user id, the API will figure out the id itself based on the access token used.